# Mapping nhibernate custom types with parameters using Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an nhibernate custom type that I would like to map with Fluent NHibernate.

The HBM mapping looks like this.

```
<property name="DateConvention" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore" column="date_convention" not-null="true">
  <type name="DataAccess.Types.DateConventionCustomType, Services.DataAccess">
    <param name="type">Services.Data.DateConventionTypeParameter, Services.Data</param>
  </type>
</property>
```

I have successfully mapped the custom type, but I cannot find a way to configure the **parameters** on the custom type mapping.

Is there a way to map this using fluent nhibernate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fluent NHibernate does not expose this capability, but you can use hbm.xml files for the mappings that need it and use ClassMap for the rest.