# NHibernate IUserType get mapped property name

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We are working on an NHibernate project where we needed to implement the NHibernate `IUserType` interface. So we did and so far it works fine (we haven't gotten around to testing the `NullSafeSet` method yet). However, we have 1 problem: We need to know what property we are mapping in order to be able to return the correct result.

#### Situation:

The value which we need to map is stored in the DB as an `int`, we need to create a **Code** object from this value. To be able to create the Code object, we require a `string` alongside with the previously mentioned `int`. This `string` is the name of the property we are mapping.

I already discovered that the `names` parameter contains the NHibernate SQL alias of the property (it was something in the form of: "IS69_6_") but I don't know whether or not this value stays the same (When i debugged it seemed to remain the same).

Some code to clarify:
*CodeTypeMapper.cs*

```cs
public class CodeTypeMapper : IUserType
{
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return x != null && x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    /********** Code relevant to the question: **********/
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var key = (int?)NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
        if (key == null) return null;
        // So here we need to be able to get the correct code.
        // In order to get the correct code, we need the key (fetched above)
        // but we also need the name of the property that we are mapping
        // which has a dummy value in this example.
        Code code = MasterMetaProvider.MasterMeta.GetCode("PropertyName", (int)key);
        if (code == null) return null;
        // Now that we have the Code object, we can use it to return the proper result
        var result = new NetworkObjectEnum((int)key, code.CodeDescEn);
        return result;
    }
    /***************************************************/

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
        }
        else
        {
            value = int.Parse(value.ToString());
            NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, value, index);
        }
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get
        {
            var types = new SqlType[1];
            types[0] = new SqlType(DbType.String);
            return types;
        }
    }
    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(NetworkObjectEnum); }
    }
    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

*The NHibernate Mapping code:*

```cs
// We need this Property's name
Map(x => x.PropertyName).Column("PropertyNameInDB").CustomType<CodeTypeMapper>();
```

---

#### Question:

So the question I want to ask: Is it possible to access the above property's name in the `CodeTypeMapper` class ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Yanik Ceulemans

---

### Update 23 Sept 2013:

As an attempt to clarify my question, I will give an example: Say there is a code table that specifies cities, types of transport, etc...:

```
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
| id | code_type | code_value | code_desc |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | city      |          5 | Antwerp   |
|  2 | city      |          8 | Brussels  |
|  3 | city      |          1 | Ghent     |
|  4 | transport |          1 | boat      |
|  5 | transport |          8 | plane     |
|  6 | transport |          9 | car       |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Next, we have a travel table that uses this code table in the following fashion:

```
+----+------+-------------------+-----------+
| id | city |   other_column    | transport |
+----+------+-------------------+-----------+
|  1 |    5 | some random value |         1 |
|  2 |    8 | randomness        |         8 |
|  3 |    1 | a value           |         9 |
+----+------+-------------------+-----------+
```

As you can see: if we want to know the description for a code, we know what value we need to take from the code table by looking at the column name, and the value in that column from the travel table.

The c# class `Travel` will probably look something like this:

```cs
public class Travel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int City { get; set; }
    public string OtherColumn { get; set; }
    public int Transport { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is: Is it possible when mapping the Travel class, to get the property name "city" inside the `IUserType` implementation at runtime in order to be able to grab the correct value from the code table ? (note: I cannot change the DB design.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design is known as a "god table" and you have my sympathies. Our main product had one of these when I started and it took me a year to normalize it.

Before the refactoring, I mapped this with NHibernate by using views to virtually normalize it. That is, create a view for city, transport, etc. and map those as if they were tables. I see that you can't change the schema but if you can add views this is a good solution.

Alternative 1: Create an IUserType implementation for each type in your code table.

Alternative 2: Prior to using views, I used NHibernate's ability to add a where clause to the mapping. I remember that there were drawbacks to this approach, one of which I think was that the where clause was not always applied as expected in queries. Using Fluent NHibernate the mapping would look like this:

```
public abstract Class CodeTableBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string CodeType { get; protected set; }
    public virtual int Value { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; protected set; }
}

public class City : CodeTableBase {}

public abstract class CodeTableMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : CodeTableBase
{
    public CodeTableMap() 
    {
        Table("CodeTable");
        Id(x => Id, "id").your id generation strategy
        CodeType(x => x.CodeType, "code_type");
        Value(x => x.Value, "code_value");
        Description(x => x.Description, "code_description");
    }

    public CodeTableMap(string codeType) : this()
    {
        Where("code_type = '" + codeType + '"); // may need to use property name
    }
}

public class CityMap : CodeTableMap<City>
{
    public CityMap : base("city") {}
}
```

Comment: We decided to go for the IUserType implementation for each type in the code table. Thx for your advice !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but maybe you need something like this:

[Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/08/05/87218.aspx)

---

Implementing IParameterizedType you can send in mapping the name of the property:

[Here](http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/usertype.html)

Fluent NHibernate does not provide capability to this but you can use xml files.

[Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665276/mapping-nhibernate-custom-types-with-parameters-using-fluent-nhibernate)

---

Other not much elegant solution:

```
var propertyName = GetPropertyName(owner.GetType(), owner, typeof(YourAttribute));

public static string GetPropertyName(Type entityType, object entity, Type attributeType)
{
    if (entity == null) return null;

    var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(entityType, attributeType);

    return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.Name;
}

public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(Type entityType, Type attributeType)
{
    return entityType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes(false)
        .Count(x => x.GetType() == attributeType) > 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your response. Sadly, I don't think the link that you provided is what I need. I've updated my question in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: Did you tried the implementation? the method NullSafeGet provides the Columns names you can use them like property name. [Fluent map example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935161/how-do-i-map-an-icompositeusertype).
Other way, maybe using Attributes to get the property name by reflection?

Comment: The column names passed to the `NullSafeGet` method (parameter `string[] names`) are in the form of "IS69_6_0" for a property called "IsElectrified" and as far as I know these are not guaranteed to stay the same. So could you perhaps explain how I can use these as property names ?

Comment: Implementing ICompositeUserType you can specify the column names:
<property name="Rate" type="Data.NHibernateImpl.Types.MoneyCompositeUserType,Data">
<column name="Amount"></column>
<column name="Currency"></column>
</property>
That names you get them in NullSafeGet Method by parameters, im not sure this will work for you, but in my implementation i got those names as column names where are the values ​​of the properties of my custom type class.